# Can you run FindMinimum excluding imaginary results?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a FindMinimum task that I described in an earlier [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123650/findminimum-works-only-if-you-know-the-answer/123662#123662).  One of the suggestions to make the minimization algorithm work was to try to scale the input variables so they are closer.  One of the options I have is to use a Log10 function to change distances into magnitudes.  However, the combination of the two input variables leads to many values that are imaginary.  The function

```
FindMinimum[{chiSquared[t1, a0]]}, {{t1, 1*^16}, {a0, 1*^-14}}]
```

fails with the message

> The function value {7.98991 (8.29281 -2.17147 Log[-1.61233*10^-20 (-3005.38+Times[<<2>>])]),6.6395 (8.40948 -2.17147 Log[-1.61233*10^-20 (-3005.38+Times[<<2>>])]),6.93242 (8.47922 -2.17147 Log[-1.61153*10^-20 (-3306.73+Times[<<2>>])]),6.96657 (8.57934 -2.17147 Log[-1.61153*10^-20 (-3306.73+Times[<<2>>])]),<<44>>,7.28976 (10.1836 -2.17147 Log[-1.60197*10^-20 (-6934.41+Times[<<2>>])]),7.52241 (10.2498 -2.17147 Log[-1.60197*10^-20 (-6934.41+Times[<<2>>])]),<<426>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {476} at {Subscript[t, 1],Subscript[a, [Placeholder]]} = {1.,1.}. >> >>

Is there a way to tell the FindMinimum function to ignore results that are imaginary?

Comment: Can't you just wrap the function in `Re[]`?

Comment: Apparently not.  I get the same message above, but with the 'Re[<previous message>]'.  Oddly, if I just take the 'chiSquared' function at the coordinates quoted in the error message (e.g. 1, 1), I get a real number.

Comment: Are you using the same definitions and values as in the post you linked to? This does not produce any error on my side.

Comment: I'm still working on it, but there seems to be a bug when using the subscript notation.  You are correct, the notation I supplied seems to work.  In my original notebook, the same values when subscripted (e.g. $t_1, a_0$) fail with the above message.

Comment: @DRAirey1 Giving `FindMinimum[{chiSquared[Subscript[t, 1], 
   Subscript[a, 0]]}, {{Subscript[t, 1], 1*^16}, {Subscript[a, 0], 
   1*^-14}}]` works fine and produces the same result as `FindMinimum[{chiSquared[t1, a0]}, {{t1, 1*^16}, {a0, 1*^-14}}]` for me.

Comment: The error message shows that the value of the function is not a complex number either.  Try plugging valid values in for the variables and see what you get.  There's something wrong with your definition.  (FWIW, I always avoid subscripts myself, except sometimes with `Format[]`. I also tend to avoid questions with subscripts. There are plenty of other questions without them. :)

Comment: I can't speak for Xavier, but removing the subscripts seems to have cleared the problem.  I like the read-ability of the subscripted notebooks - it looks more like what I write by hand - but I'm having second thoughts about the practice.